# Need to show costs for last 6 months on complicated sub queries

Tags: mysql, select

I know how to get the figures for the last 6 months on a single query, but I have a query that gets the figures from multiple sub queries and I need to show just the last 6 months.

Here is my current query

```
SELECT `totalSales`,`totalPurchase`,`totalNetpay`,`totalPension`,`totalP32`
FROM
(SELECT SUM((`Unit_Cost`*`ExchangeRate`)*`Quantity`) AS `totalSales` FROM `salesinvoice_products` AS `prod`
LEFT JOIN `salesinvoice` AS `inv` on `prod`.`SalesInvoice_id`=`inv`.`SalesInvoice_id`) as `t1`,

(SELECT SUM((`InvoiceValue`*`ExchangeRate`)-`VATValue`) as `totalPurchase` FROM `purchaseinvoice`) as `t2`,

(SELECT SUM(`NetAmountPaid`) as `totalNetpay` FROM `payroll_netpay`) as `t3`,

(SELECT SUM(`totalAmountDue`) as `totalPension` FROM `payroll_pensionrecords`) as `t4`,

(SELECT SUM(`totalAmountDue`) as `totalP32` FROM `payroll_p32records`) as `t5`
```

As you can see I have 5 subqueries. This at the moment gives me the output
3122.051719,2173.911200,10019.00,7351.56,2231.43

What I want however is to get 6 lines from the last 6 months. However when I try to do this I get multiple lines instead of 6. I think somehow I have to group them in some way.

Ok so now I will show you the code where I tried to get it working.

```
SELECT `InvoiceDate`,`totalSales`,`totalPurchase`,`totalNetpay`,`totalPension`,`totalP32`
FROM
(SELECT SUM((`Unit_Cost`*`ExchangeRate`)*`Quantity`) AS `totalSales`,`InvoiceDate` FROM `salesinvoice_products` AS `prod`
LEFT JOIN `salesinvoice` AS `inv` on `prod`.`SalesInvoice_id`=`inv`.`SalesInvoice_id`
WHERE (`InvoiceDate` < Now() and `InvoiceDate` > DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL- 6 MONTH)) && `InvoiceType`>1
 GROUP BY MONTH(`InvoiceDate`)
) as `t1`,

(SELECT SUM((`InvoiceValue`*`ExchangeRate`)-`VATValue`) as `totalPurchase` FROM `purchaseinvoice`
WHERE (`InvoiceDate` < Now() and `InvoiceDate` > DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL- 6 MONTH))
 GROUP BY MONTH(`InvoiceDate`)
) as `t2`,


(SELECT SUM(`NetAmountPaid`) as `totalNetpay` FROM `payroll_netpay`
 WHERE (`Date` < Now() and `Date` > DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL- 6 MONTH))
  GROUP BY MONTH(`Date`)
) as `t3`,


(SELECT SUM(`totalAmountDue`) as `totalPension` FROM `payroll_pensionrecords`
 WHERE (`datePaid` < Now() and `datePaid` > DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL- 6 MONTH))
  GROUP BY MONTH(`datePaid`)
 ) as `t4`,

(SELECT SUM(`totalAmountDue`) as `totalP32` FROM `payroll_p32records`
  WHERE (`datePaid` < Now() and `datePaid` > DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL- 6 MONTH))
  GROUP BY MONTH(`datePaid`)
) as `t5`
```

As you can guess this query actually works, but instead of getting 6 lines I get 20 odd lines. I know I have to group them in some way, but I am not sure how? The biggest problem is that the different tables have a different named date field, which I cannot change at this stage.

edit--
I have tried a different way. I have cut down my query to two items to make it easier. If I use between it works,but I would have to feed in the different months somehow.

```
SELECT `totalSales`,`totalPurchase`
FROM
(SELECT SUM((`Unit_Cost`*`ExchangeRate`)*`Quantity`) AS `totalSales` FROM `salesinvoice_products` AS `prod`
LEFT JOIN `salesinvoice` AS `inv` on `prod`.`SalesInvoice_id`=`inv`.`SalesInvoice_id`
WHERE `InvoiceDate` BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-26'
) as `t1`,

(SELECT SUM((`InvoiceValue`*`ExchangeRate`)-`VATValue`) as `totalPurchase` FROM `purchaseinvoice`
WHERE `InvoiceDate` BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-26'
) as `t2`
```

What this does is give me data for one month, but it doesn't really help on my initial query too much, but something else I have tried.

Comment: Ridiculous. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Nice I have read that whole page and not once on that page does it say what MCVE means which is truly unhelpful. As for showing create and insert I haven't used them as I build the database in dbforge, and I have shown my best effort to date with my second piece of code. As for the relationships these would not make any difference in the code above. There really should be enough information in my above code to provide a solution. Will probably end up solving it myself.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't actually read the whole page.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams The entire guidance Strawberry created and linked into this question is about MCVE. Since your queries are syntactically correct, just do not return the expected resultset, therefore you should provide some sample data and explain what you are trying to implement. In its current form, I have no idea what you are after, and judging from the close and down votes, I'm not alone with this problem. You can lash out at Strawberry as much as you want, but this will not get you far in getting an answer.

Comment: I thought it was plain what I was after. The first query gives me totals, but I want the totals for the last 6 months. The second mysql code shows what I have tried but obviously doesn't work. All the fields are there for anyone to see. As for MCVE I don't even know what the Acronym is. I have read that whole page that Strawberry gave and not once does it tell me what it is.

Comment: As evidenced by 4 close votes and 4 downvotes, what's plain is that you're mistaken - on two counts.

Comment: @Shadow: I hardly think that my reply was lashing out. I was simply stating that I didn't understand what MCVE meant. I now do understand what it means, but I haven't worked out how to create one of these online databases. It is a little beyond me. I am not sure how these fiddle things work. It seems that you can only get help if you already know how to do something, which means a beginner like me will never get help. I will try and find the time to learn how these fiddle things work, but at the moment I am a little pushed for time. I have a temporary solution which I will post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right I have an answer which works, but it is not the best solution by any means. I really wanted to answer my question with one query, but the only solution I have come up with is to use php and loop the mysql. Yes I know this is not ideal, but I needed to find a solution quickly and even though it isn't the best way, it works. I will carry on and see if I can work out a way of doing this with JUST mysql, but at the moment this will have to do.

Basically my query is doing one month at a time. So I have to increment the month in php and re-run the query for all 6 months.

Looking for a better solution now.

```
$plArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++):
    $month  = date("m", strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01' )." -$i months"));
    $query="SELECT IFNULL(`totalSales`,0)-IFNULL(`totalPurchase`,0)-(IFNULL(`totalNetpay`,0)+IFNULL(`totalP32`,0)+IFNULL(`totalPension`,0)) as `totalPL`";
    $query.="
    FROM (SELECT SUM((`Unit_Cost`*`ExchangeRate`)*`Quantity`) AS `totalSales` FROM `salesinvoice_products` AS `prod`
    LEFT JOIN `salesinvoice` AS `inv` on `prod`.`SalesInvoice_id`=`inv`.`SalesInvoice_id`
    WHERE MONTH(`InvoiceDate`)=?
    ) as `t1`,

    (SELECT SUM((`InvoiceValue`*`ExchangeRate`)-`VATValue`) as `totalPurchase` FROM `purchaseinvoice`
    WHERE MONTH(`InvoiceDate`)=?
    ) as `t2`,

    (SELECT SUM(`NetAmountPaid`) as `totalNetpay` FROM `payroll_netpay`
    WHERE MONTH(`Date`)=?
    ) as `t3`,

    (SELECT SUM(`totalAmountDue`) as `totalPension` FROM `payroll_pensionrecords`
    WHERE MONTH(`datePaid`)=?
    ) as `t4`,

    (SELECT SUM(`totalAmountDue`) as `totalP32` FROM `payroll_p32records`
    WHERE MONTH(`datePaid`)=?
    ) as `t5`";
    $stmt = $this->logon->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('iiiii',$month,$month,$month,$month,$month);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $this->functions->get_result($stmt);
    $plArray[] = array(
    'date' => date("Y-m", strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01' )." -$i months")),
    'total' => $result[0]['totalPL']
    );
endfor;
```